# Errors "0: 'Open' is not defined" and "SCRIPT1005: SCRIPT1005: Expected '('" How do I fix these errors?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Problem with oneclick only in Microsoft edge.

[image]

```js
function closepage(){
 var Modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
 var Modalparent = null;
 try{ Modalparent = ((Modal.parentElement) ? Modal.parentElement : ((Modal.parentNode) ? Modal.parentNode : null));}catch{return;}
 if(Modalparent == null)return;
 Modalparent.removeChild(Modal);
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `catch` argument like this in Edge:

```
try{
  ...
} catch(error){
  ...
}
```

`try{...}catch{...}` without argument is called [Optional catch binding](https://2ality.com/2017/08/optional-catch-binding.html) which is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Browser_compatibility) by Edge.

So the code sample which can work is like below:

```js
function closepage() {
  var Modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
  var Modalparent = null;
  try {
    Modalparent = ((Modal.parentElement) ? Modal.parentElement : ((Modal.parentNode) ? Modal.parentNode : null));
  } catch (error) {
    return;
  }
  if (Modalparent == null) return;
  Modalparent.removeChild(Modal);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="Modal">Modal</div>
<button onclick="closepage()" type="button">test</button>
```